# Rescaling Dicom pixel values to be in the range [0,1]

Tags: python-3.7, pydicom

I haven't been able to find the range of values that is returned from .pixel_array so I'm not sure how to scale the values to a custom range like [0,1]. Is there a pydicom inbuilt function that does this already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of *Bits Stored* and *Pixel Representation* should be enough for *Pixel Data*:

```py
from pydicom import dcmread

ds = dcmread("/path/to/dataset")
if ds.PixelRepresentation == 0:
    # Unsigned integers
    min_px = 0
    max_px = 2**ds.BitsStored - 1
else:
   # Signed integers
    min_px = -2**(ds.BitsStored - 1)
    max_px = 2**(ds.BitsStored - 1) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now using this information how can I re-scale the values to be within the range [0,1]

Comment: Unsigned ints: divide values by `ds.BitsStored**2 - 1`, signed ints: add `(ds.BitsStored - 1)**2)` then divide by `ds.BitsStored**2 - 1`